# Como retornar celulas com base no identificador no R

Tags: r

preciso retornar a classe de um id específico para uma tabela. Muitas vezes um único id codifica várias classes:

```
id<-c("A","B","C","D","C","B","A")
clas<-c(1,2,2,2,3,3,4)
tab<-data.frame(id,clas)
```

O que eu preciso é fazer um data.frame que retorne da seguinte forma:

```
   id clas
1  1    A
2  2  BCD
3  3   CB
4  4    A
```

Alguém pode me ajudar

Answer (score 4):

Uma forma relativamente simples de fazer isso é usando o `dplyr`:

```
tab <- tab %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(clas = paste0(clas, collapse = ""))
```

Resultado:

```
> tab
# A tibble: 4 × 2
     id  clas
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1     A
2     2   BCD
3     3    CB
4     4     A
```

Comment: Sua ideia foi ótima e muito simples, uma pequenina correção no script é trocar id com clas:
tab_resutlado <- tab %>%
  group_by(clas) %>%
  summarise(id = paste0(id, collapse = ""))

Comment: Tem problema fazer isso com uma tabela de 1 milhão de linhas? ele fica resumindo as classes em 6 linhas e não retornando a tabela

Comment: Não deveria... Tem certeza que você quer fazer o group pela clas? EU acho que no seu exemplo que está invertido!